# looks like df.drop() doesn't the job for a datetime index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

It looks like `df.drop()` is not working as expected (Note the index is a DatetimeIndex):

```
>>> df
                            price  bidvol  askvol
datetime
2014-07-16 14:23:46.653000  34911       0       1
2014-07-16 14:23:53.705000  34909       5       0
2014-07-16 14:23:55.326000  34909       2       0
2014-07-16 14:23:59.539000  34908       1       0
2014-07-16 14:23:59.539000  34908       9       0
2014-07-16 14:24:00.219000  34908       2       0

>>> df = df.drop(df.ix['2014-07-16 14:24':])

>>> df
                             price  bidvol  askvol
datetime
2014-07-16 14:23:46.653000  34911       0       1
2014-07-16 14:23:53.705000  34909       5       0
2014-07-16 14:23:55.326000  34909       2       0
2014-07-16 14:23:59.539000  34908       1       0
2014-07-16 14:23:59.539000  34908       9       0
2014-07-16 14:24:00.219000  34908       2       0
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: df.index
Out[50]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-16 10:00:00.006000, ..., 2014-07-16 14:24:11.462000]
Length: 51225, Freq: None, Timezone: None

Comment: thnx Andy for the formatting. i'll improve my skill.

Answer (score 0):

```
date = '2014-07-16 14:24'
```

To drop a range:

```
df = df[:date] # Drops anything after the date
df = df[date:] # Drops anything before the date
```

To drop a row:

```
df = df.drop(Timestamp(date)) # Drops the row indexed by the date
```

It is not that drop doesn't work for dates. It seems instead that it does not automatically converts strings to dates as slice indexing does.

Check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: 2. waht should I do to cut some range? thnx

Comment: Please print the headers of your dataframe too. I would like to see which columns are indexes, and what are the names of the columns.

Comment: [quote]df.head() 
Out[51]:  
                            price  bidvol  askvol
datetime                                         
2014-07-16 10:00:00.006000  34911       1       0
2014-07-16 10:00:00.006000  34908       1       0
2014-07-16 10:00:00.006000  34907       5       0
2014-07-16 10:00:00.006000  34905       1       0
2014-07-16 10:00:00.006000  34905       2       0[/quote]

Comment: i'm very new here. i'm trying :) thnx

Comment: to drop a range in a middle of the df. thnx

Comment: Please edit your question, so it asks specifically about dropping a row. The way it is written right now it suggests that you want to drop a range, and that's why I answered it that way. Is my edited answer what you were looking for?

Comment: the fact is df.drop() doesn't work with datetime index as expected. so the question is correct, imho. thnx.

Comment: pls, look at the index. pls, look at the qstn. the request should drop everything before 2014-07-16 14:24, but it doesn't. you gave the workaround but the problem is still there: df.drop() doesn't work with datetime index.